# Would using webview with phonegap get an app rejected from Apple App Store?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, webview, cordova

Would using webview with phonegap get an app rejected from Apple App Store? The app would not be all in webview, but will using webview for certain things make apple reject the app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. 
See the PhoneGap [FAQ](http://wiki.phonegap.com/FAQ).
Also see this [post](http://blogs.nitobi.com/jesse/2010/04/14/phonegap-and-the-apple-developer-license-agreement/).